# Can one pass Perl object references between modules?

Tags: perl, class, module, reference, perl-module

Example code:

#### testClass1.pm

```
package testClass1; 
{
my $testClass2Ref;

sub new
{
    my($class) = shift;
    $testClass2Ref= shift;
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;}
}

sub testRef
{
    $testClass2Ref->testRef;
}
}
```

#### testClass2.pm

```
package testClass2; 
{

sub new
{
    my($class) = shift;
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;}
}

sub testRef
{
    print "Test 2";
}
}
```

#### test.pl

```
use testClass1;
use testClass2;

my $testClass2 = testClass2->new();
my $testClass1 = testClass2->new($testClass2);
$testClass1->testRef;
```

When I try call `$testClass1->testRef`, `$testClass2Ref=undef`.

How can I pass reference on the object from parent?

#### Update

Oh, sorry, I missed string in example's constructors.

```
sub new
{
    my($class) = shift;
    $testClass2Ref = shift;
    my $self    = {name=>'testClass1'};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

This test is working, but Eclipse debugger show this variables as 'undef'.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8592033/edit) and fix the syntax errors. When I run the program after making the necessary minimal changes (unbalanced braces, true value at end of class), I get `Can't bless non-reference value at testClass2.pm line 7.` You make it difficult to help if we are not able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the syntax errors, you aren't using `strict` mode. Turning it on will reveal that `$self` isn't being declared in either package. By replacing:

```
bless $self, $class;
```

with:

```
my $self = bless {}, $class;
```

Everything goes through as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you fix the syntax errors it works.

```
> ./test.pl
> Test 2
```

You were missing

```
my $self = {};
```

in both `new` methods.

A useful tool is

```
perl -wc testClass1.pm
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can one pass Perl object references between modules?

Absolutely!

In this test script I make two classes, one that tests and one to be tested. Remember objects are just references and methods are just subroutines; use them in the same way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package Tester;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my ($other) = @_;

  my $self = { other => $other };
  bless $self, $class;

  return $self;
}

sub examine { 
  my $self = shift; 
  print "I'm holding a: ", ref( $self->{other} ), "\n";
}

package Candidate;

sub new { return bless {}, shift }

package main;

my $candidate = Candidate->new();
my $tester = Tester->new( $candidate );

$tester->examine();
```

**EDIT:** Now using a more modern system, [`MooseX::Declare`](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aDeclare) (which is based on [`Moose`](http://p3rl.org/Moose)) with [`Method::Signatures`](http://p3rl.org/Method%3a%3aSignatures). This saves a lot of the boilerplate and lets you focus on what you want the objects to do, rather then how they are implemented.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

#technically Moose adds strict and warnings, but ...
use strict;
use warnings; 

use MooseX::Declare;
use Method::Signatures::Modifiers;

class Tester {
  has 'other' => ( isa => 'Object', is => 'rw', required => 1 );

  method examine () {
    print "I'm holding a: ", ref( $self->other() ), "\n";
  }
}

class Candidate { }

no MooseX::Declare;

package main;

my $candidate = Candidate->new();
my $tester = Tester->new( other => $candidate );

$tester->examine();
```

For more realistic cases, see how some larger module systems pass object representing complex concepts. Off the top of my head, [`HTTP::Response`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aResponse) object get passed around all through the [`LWP`](http://p3rl.org/LWP) system