# Manipulate Perl object by reference in subroutine

Tags: perl, object, reference, perl-module, subroutine

I have a Perl program and packages `Worker` and `Log`.

The Worker does almost all calculations, and I want to pass an object by reference to the Worker subroutine, as well as some other parameters (scalar and an array). I have seen examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683370/how-should-i-pass-objects-to-subroutines) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592033/can-one-pass-perl-object-references-between-modules).

They handle this by putting `@_` in subs, then manipulating the object. I also found a way to manipulate them by using the index, like `@{$_[i]}`. Problem is, when I try the code like so, I get an error:
`Can't call method "write" on unblessed reference at ...`

Code snippets below.

Main:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Log;
use Worker;

my $log = Log->new();
my $worker = Worker->new();
my $scalar = "SomeURLhere";
my @array = ('red','blue','white');

# I do some stuff with $log object
#...
# Now I want to pass data to the Worker
$worker->subFromWorker($scalar, \$log, \@array);
```

#### Worker:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
package Worker;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub subFromWorker{
    my ($self) = shift;
    my $scalar = $_[0];
    #my ($log) = $_[1];
    my @array = @{$_[2]};

    foreach my $item (@array){
        print $item;
    }

    $_[1]->write("The items from url $scalar are printed.");

    #Same thing happens if I use $log here
}
```

In C#, this is handled in a different way - you can send a parameter to a method by value or by reference, and then do what you want in a specialized method (method is pre-written to handle parameters by reference or value). I thought that in Perl sending using `\parameter` will send the reference.

Comment: When you say you have a package `Main` do you just mean it's your program? It should be in a `*.pl` file

Comment: @Borodin A program, I'll amend the question.

Comment: *"(method is pre-written to handle parameters by reference or value)"* It is exactly the same with Perl. If you pass an object by reference (although it is a strange thing to do) then you have to treat it as such in the method. If you pass `\$log` then you would have to write `${$log}->write( ... )` (assuming you had already pulled `$log` out of the paremeters with `my $log = $_[1]`)

Comment: Re "In C#, this is handled in a different way - you can send a parameter to a method by value or by reference", Perl always passes by reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objects are references. References are scalar values.

If you want to pass arrays or hashes into a subroutine then you usually want to pass references to them - because Perl parameter passing works far better with scalar values.

But `$log` is already a reference to your object. Therefore you don't need to take a reference to it. You end up passing a reference to a reference. So when you copy that parameter into `$log` inside your subroutine you have an extra, unnecessary, level of references.

The fix is to just pass the `$log` scalar into the subroutine.

```
$worker->subFromWorker($scalar, $log, \@array); # $log, not \$log
```

Everything else will then work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You have read about the issues that prevent your program from working, but there are a few other things you should be aware of

- Perl lexical identifiers and subroutine/method names consist of alphanumerics and underscore. Capital letters are reserved for global identifiers, such as package names like `Worker` and `Log`.
- Packages that you `use` or `require` should end with the statement `1;` so as to return a *true* value when they are imported, otherwise your program may fail to compile.
- If a subroutine that you are writing happens to be a *method*, then it is clearest to start it by shifting off the `$self` parameter and making a copy of the rest:

  ```
  my $self = shift;
  my ($p1, $p2, $p3) = @_;
  ```

  It is rare to use elements of `@_` directly unless you're desperate for the minimal speed bonus
- It is usually best to work directly with an array reference rather than copying the array, especially if it may be large.

Here is how I would code your program and associated modules:

#### program.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Worker;
use Log;

my $log    = Log->new;
my $worker = Worker->new;

my $scalar = 'SomeURLhere';
my @array  = qw/ red blue white /;

$worker->worker_method($scalar, $log, \@array);
```

#### Worker.pm

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Worker;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self  = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub worker_method {
    my $self   = shift;
    my ($scalar, $log, $array) = @_;

    foreach my $item (@$array) {
        print $item, "\n";
    }

    $log->write("The items from URL $scalar are printed.");
}

1;
```

#### Log.pm

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Log;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    bless {}, $class;
}

sub write {
    my $self   = shift;
    my ($text) = @_;

    print "Logging: $text\n"
}

1;
```

#### Output

```
red
blue
white
Logging: The items from URL SomeURLhere are printed.
```

Answer (score 0):

A more common pattern is to use List assignment to unpack `@_` into multiple variables all at once:

```
sub subFromWorker {
   my ($self, $scalar, $log_ref, $array) = @_;
   ...
}
```

In reference to your specific problem:

```
my $log = Log->new();
```

`$log` is *already* a reference to your object, using `\$log` creates a reference to that reference which is not probably not what you want. You can handle this two ways:

1. only pass `$log`:

   - `$worker->subFromWorker($scalar, $log, \@array);`
2. dereference `$log` in `subFromWorker` before calling functions on it:

   - `$$log_ref->write('...');`

Comment: I like: `my $self = shift; my ($scalar, $log_ref, $array) = @_;` because a) it emphasises that `$self` is a special parameter and b) it leaves `@_` containing the actual list of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but like I wrote in the question, I saw solutions with `@_` and the other method is more user friendly, at least to myself.

Comment: @DaveCross a good point, but I happen to like doing it this way. I do sometimes use `shift` especially when I have a sub that is going to delegate all of its work to another sub (maybe a private one): `sub public { my $self = shift; return $self->_private(@_); }`